# How can I change my code to get URL link from the HTML code?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I try to use beautifulsoup4 to **scrape** the URL of the HTML code in python, but I got the error like this: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

HTML code:

```html
<a class="top NQHJEb dfhHve" href="https://globalnews.ca/news/5137005/donald-trump-robert-mueller-report/" ping="/url?sa=t&amp;source=web&amp;rct=j&amp;url=https://globalnews.ca/news/5137005/donald-trump-robert-mueller-report/&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiS9pn-4rzhAhWOyIMKHSOPD6QQvIgBCDcwAg"><img class="th BbeB2d" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ_Nf-kVlqsQz8NeNgQ9a9YRiA7Fl4DJ6Jod0sxNXapOK_iJebx20dgROk5YBl8IqFQX6S-eeY2" alt="Story image for trump from Globalnews.ca" onload="typeof google==='object'&amp;&amp;google.aft&amp;&amp;google.aft(this)" data-iml="1554598687532" data-atf="3"></a>
```

My python code:

```
URL_results = soup.find_all('a', class_= 'top NQHJEb dfhHve').get('href')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the method to a list. Instead you want to apply to each element

```
URL_results = [a.attrs.get('href') for a in soup.find_all('a', class_= 'top NQHJEb dfhHve')]
```

I prefer

```
URL_results = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('a.top.NQHJEb.dfhHve')]
```

And you may be able to remove some of the classes from the current compound class selector e.g.

```
URL_results = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('a.dfhHve')]
```

You will need to play around and see.